Issue with PKCE Authentication Flow for Azure AD B2C: "The supplied code_verifier is invalid"
I am currently trying to use the PKCE method of obtaining an access token for Azure AD B2C to pass to my Azure Function APIs in API Management. I am passing the below URL into my browser to generate the "code" query parameter on login:
https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{user-flow}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=_&response_type=code&redirect_uri=_&scope=_&code_challenge=_&code_challenge_method=S256

I am able to log in, however when I do log in I recieve the below error message:
AADB2C90183: The supplied code_verifier is invalid

I was expecting to get a valid response, as I've tried the same URL without the code_challenge and code_challenge_method query parameters, and I can authenticate properly. The issue with doing this method is that it requires the client_secret value for the next step. This is why I am trying to use PKCE in the first place, because it doesn't require a client_secret to access tokens.
I've also tried different websites to generate code_verifier and code_challenge, even making an Azure Function to create these values, however I still get returned the same error.
I am confused on how to approach the issue because when I try logging into the URL without the code_challenge and code_challenge_method, the URL works in the auth flow (just not with PKCE like I want), however when I use websites and my own code to generate the code_verifier and code_challenge, I still receive the same error. Does anyone have any insights on this issue?

Using "S256" as the code challenge method, your code_challenge needs to be the base64-urlencoded SHA256 hash of the ASCII encoding of the code verifier.
Now I don't know if you mean that you are literally using '_' as the code_challenge, but that's obviously not a valid value for a S256 code_challenge.
I also don't know which code_challenge / code_verifier pairs you used when you generated them, but it might help if I took you through how you might generate a valid pair and you can see if that works for you.
First, generate a code_verifier.  This needs to be a cryptographically secure random string between 43 and 128 chars long consisting of the characters [A-Z] / [a-z] / [0-9] / "-" / "." / "_" / "~".
Then you need to generate the code_challenge using the method described above. For example, in Python I would do:
import secrets
import hashlib
import base64

code_verifier = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)
h = hashlib.sha256(code_verifier.encode('ascii')).digest()
code_challenge = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(h).rstrip(b'=').decode('ascii')

You then pass the code_challenge in the initial authorization request, and then pass the code_verifier in the token request once you receive the authorization code from the OIDC redirect.
You should also check the other parameters in your request - redirect_uri should match one of the pre-registered redirect URIs for example. Again I'm unsure if you are literally using "_" here.

Hi, yeah I was not using "" as the code challenge, sorry for the confusion. The "" was more for placeholder values. It turns out that after authenticating, the code produced after logging in actually works with obtaining an access token, just for some reason I'm getting this error message returned.
